# Can regex_iterators be used on a custom string type?

Tags: c++, regex

I have only found examples of `regex_iterators` being intialised as

```
regex_iterator::<string::iterator>
```

If I have a class which contains a sequence of characters, such as:

```
class fooString {
private:
  deque<bar> data;

  // ... other functionality ...
}
```

Where `bar` is a class or struct that is compatible with `std::to_string`

How would I make `fooString` and `bar` compatible with regex so that I could call

```
fooString myFoo = ...
regex e( /* some regex notation */);
regex_iterator::<fooString::iterator> regIt(myFoo.begin(), myFoo.end(), e);
```

...and be able to iterate over it as I would with a string?

---

I tried the following experiement:

```
    std::deque<int> testDeque { 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7 };
    std::regex e("5{1,3}");
    std::regex_iterator<std::deque<int>::iterator> 
    regIt(testDeque.begin(), testDeque.end(), e);
```

And get the compilation error

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\regex(2271): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::regex_traits<_Elem>'
with  
[  
   _Elem=int  
]
```

So I don't think the bidirectional iterator is enough since deque complies with that, I think the 'bar' object needs to be compatible. But I'm really not sure.

Comment: According to [this `std::regex_iterator` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator), the iterator needs to be a [bidirectional iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator). So if your iterator fulfills the requirements of a bidirectional iterator, you're good to go.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think the data type Bar also needs to fullfill some particular property, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fooString` must satisfy the requirements of a bidirectional iterator. [bidirectional.iterators] [cppreference's documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator) is *extremely* close to the standard wording, so you'd be okay following it.

I will add the relevant portions here:

- The iterator, `r`, must satisfy both operations `--r` and `r++`

  - these operations return a reference to an iterator of the same type
- `*r` must return a reference to the type the iterator is iterating over.

  - a `reference` type according to what [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) lists for `iterator_traits`

If your `BidirectionalIterator::value_type` is not a standard character type (anything you could make a `std::basic_string` with, e.g., `char`), you'll also need to specialize [`regex_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_traits), although this is going down quite the rabbit hole.

Comment: I tried creating a simple test using regex_iterator<std::deque<uint32_t>::iterator>  however the constructor complains that "regex(2271): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::regex_traits<_Elem>' - with _Elem=unsigned int    So unless I'm mistaken satifying the bidirectional iterator isn't enough - regex only works with some data types.

Comment: @Ian: Why `uint32_t`? You'll need a character type.

Comment: for my real situation I'm using a custom struct (Bar), I picked uint32_t because I thought it was a simple type to test with. I also tested with int with the same result.   - What I'm really asking is how do I make a FooString containing a structure of Bars work? I think both the FooString and the Bar need some special sauce and while FooString might be the bidirectional iterator I don't know what it is for Bar.

Comment: @Ian: I have updated the post to discuss regex_traits, but I don't understand why you changed to `int` instead of a `char` [it works fine with `char`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YBZuGqfLerMrk4oz)

Comment: that regex_traits is exactly what I needed. Implementing custom behavior for types other than char and w_char will achieve what I need! Thanks.